# git tfs clone throws not a git command

Tags: git, tfs

I am trying to clone code from tfs but I am getting the following issue

```
git tfs help
```

> git : 'tfs' is not a git command

git version is `2.13.3.windows.1` is being installed on my machine.

Comment: Use just `git clone [repo-url]`

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Do you have a TFVC (need to install https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/ ) or a git repository (just a `git clone`  is required)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to clone a regular Git repo that happens to be hosted in TFS/VSTS, you can just use regular `git clone`.

If you're trying to convert a TFVC repository to a Git repository, you have to install `git-tfs` and add it to your `PATH` environment variable, or directly run `git-tfs`. `git-tfs` is a totally separate tool, written and maintained by a third party, and is not part of a standard Git installation.

Comment: Maintained by me ;)

Answer (score 1):

As Daniel mentioned, `git` and `git-tfs` is different tool. If you only want to clone repos, `git clone` would meet your requirement.

You could get more information of Git Reference in the following link:

https://git-scm.com/docs